# S3 SWF Uploader callbacks - RoR 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get [S3 SWF Uploader plugin](https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin) working on my Heroku hosted RoR app.

At this point i have it installed, and i can upload files to my Amazon bucket... that's great!

**But how can i get my hands on the callback functions?** I simply can't find them!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He has a list of all the Javascript callbacks in the README on GitHub: https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin

He also has a sample app which shows the code and how he's using the callbacks: http://s3swfuploader.heroku.com/

The one you'd be interested in is: `:onUploadingFinish ()`